# Easy way to add experimental consistently css for multiple browsers?

Tags: gradient, css

I was wondering if there was a tool that can "pre-process" CSS and automatically add experimental properties so they'll look the same on browsers that support it. For example, instead of writing:

```
.class {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px }
```

I could just write:

```
.class {
    border-radius: 8px }
```

And the others would be automatically added. For border radius it's not too bad, but it is for gradients. To accomplish the same result:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00abeb, #fff);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff));
```

[LESS](http://lesscss.org/) would be perfect if it had a feature like this. Does anyone know of a tool that does have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have to read the documentation more carefully. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) does indeed support this feature. (And it was on the front page!)

Here's a [tutorial](http://blog.smokinggun.com/simplify-css3-with-helper-functions-3) for the people looking at this question

Answer (score 2):

You could also try Compass. Compass has a CSS3 library premade :) (compass is just a mashup of blueprint framework and SASS)

http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/compass/css3/shared/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the kind of thing that [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) should be able to do.

Comment: Nice. Now that I looked more carefully at the documentation, seems like I can do it with LESS. That's what I get for not RTFM